# Why is my pytorch classification model not learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, classification

I have created a simple pytorch classification model with sample datasets generated using sklearns `make_classification`. Even after training for thousands of epochs the accuracy of the model hovers between 30 and 40 percentage. During training itself the loss value is fluctuating very far and wide. I am wondering why this model is not learning, whether it's due to some logical error in the code.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X,y = make_classification(n_features=15,n_classes=5,n_informative=4)

DEVICE = torch.device('cuda')
epochs = 5000

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,X,y):
        self.X =  torch.from_numpy(X)
        self.y = torch.from_numpy(y)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        X = self.X[index]
        y = self.y[index]
        return (X,y)

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(15,10)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(10,5)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.l1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.l2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x

model = Model().double().to(DEVICE)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
train_data = CustomDataset(X_train,y_train)
test_data = CustomDataset(X_test,y_test)

trainloader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
testloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

for i in range(epochs):
    for (x,y) in trainloader:
        x = x.to(DEVICE)
        y = y.to(DEVICE)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(x)
        loss = loss_function(output,y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    if i%200==0:
        print("epoch: ",i," Loss: ",loss.item())

correct = 0
total = 0
# since we're not training, we don't need to calculate the gradients for our outputs
with torch.no_grad():
    for x, y in testloader:
        
        # calculate outputs by running x through the network
        outputs = model(x.to(DEVICE)).to(DEVICE)
        # the class with the highest energy is what we choose as prediction
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += y.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == y.to(DEVICE)).sum().item()

    print(f'Accuracy of the network on the test data: {100 * correct // total} %')
```

EDIT

I tried to over-fit my model with only 10 samples (batch_size=5) `X,y = make_classification(n_samples=10,n_features=15,n_classes=5,n_informative=4)` but now the accuracy decreased to 15-20%. I then normalize the input data between the values 0 and 1 which pushed the accuracy a bit higher but not over 50 percentage. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using ReLU activation on your output layer. Usually softmax activation is used for multi class classification on the final layer, or the logits are fed to the loss function directly without explicitly adding a softmax activation layer.

Try removing the ReLU activation from the final layer.